# Scraping and saving multiple elements to list in one function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping

I am trying to create a neat array that stores the following key value pairs:

1. cafename: "scraped name"
2. cafeaddress: "scraped address"
3. cafedescription: "scraped description"

I have written the code that can scrape each of these elements when run as seperate functions (so one element is scraped per function = 3 functions). But now I am trying to reduce the amount of repetition by having one function that scrapes all 3 things and then appends them to a list.

Right now when I try with the below code it simply returns the description, which is the last element in the `cafes_container = soup_cafes.findAll(attrs={"class": "venue-title", "class": "address-content", "class": "venue-description"})` line of script.

The entire code block is this:

```
def cafes():
    url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury'
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafes = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafes)

    cafes_container = soup_cafes.findAll(attrs={"class": "venue-title", "class": "address-content", "class": "venue-description"})
    
    cafes = []
    for container in cafes_container:
        cafes.append(container.text)

    return(cafes)
```

Comment: While legal, the dictionary `{"class":"venue-title", "class":"address-content", "class":"venue-description"}` is equivalent to `{"class":"venue-description"}`. Why does this surprise you? What did you think a dictionary did?

Comment: Also, you don't have any arrays here. Those are lists, and yes, there's a semantic difference in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary `{"class":"venue-title", "class":"address-content", "class":"venue-description"}` is equivalent to `{"class":"venue-description"}`. This should come as no surprise, given that the whole point of a dictionary is to have unique keys. Each literal definition just overwrites the previous value. And in fact you observed this exact behavior.

You can use that to your advantage by setting the value in a dictionary over and over:

```
cafe_classes = ["venue-title", "address-content", "venue-description"]

cafes = []
for cafe_class in cafe_classes:
    cafes.append(soup_cafes.find(attrs={"class": cafe_class}).text)
```

At this point, a comprehension may be simpler to read and write:

```
cafe_classes = ["venue-title", "address-content", "venue-description"]
cafes = [soup_cafes.find(attrs={"class": c}).text for c in cafe_classes]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out. I appreciate it. The .text seems to cause me a problem resulting in this: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: @deadant88. Well, did you?

Comment: I've gone ahead and used find. Seems like a reasonable thing to do